# Probllem with install vb2Py "This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip"

Tags: python

I have a problem with installing some library converting VBA code to Python code. When I type:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org vb2py
```

i get output like this:

````
error: legacy-install-failure```

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> simpleparse

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
````

Comment: have you tried installing `simpleparse` on it's own?

Comment: Yes and i get the same output

Comment: ```note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> SimpleParse

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.```

Comment: Are you using the most recent python 3 Version? Because there have been some compatibility issues with simpleparse in the past in older python versions.

Comment: Yes, my version is 3.10.6

Answer (score 1):

just installed vb2py today on a PC. It seems that simpleparse installation happened without any problem. You can try to install it directly from https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpleparse/files/

Simpleparse latest version is there available as an .exe

Comment: that's great but this exe is only for python 2.7. But i think it's not to hard to install python 2.7 xd thanks!

Answer (score -1):

i just formatted my PC last weekend. Running Windows 10.

I downloaded and installed Anaconda. In Anaconda prompt, i called "pip install vb2py". It worked. Just converted a .bas file. No complains about simpleparse.

It didnt looks like that the python 2.7 was necessary here. I barely know how to create an environment